# Inverse of orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have an $N \times N$ orthogonal projection matrix $P = A^H(AA^H)^{-1}A$ that I'm trying to find the inverse for. I'm using matlab, however, I keep getting the warning "the matrix is close to singular or badly scaled". Now I'm wondering if it's even invertible.

Are orthogonal projection matrices invertible and if so, is there any stable method for computing the inverse?

Comment: using $A$ and $A^{\dagger}$ (psuedo-inverse) appropriately will give you the projection matrix

Answer (score 16):

If a projection matrix is invertible then it is the identity matrix.

This is because projection matrices satisfy $P^2 = P$ or $P(P - I) = 0$.  If $P$ is invertible then this implies $P - I = 0$ or $P = I$.

Another way of seeing that projections are usually not invertible is to think about their nullspace.  If you are projecting onto a space of smaller dimension then the nullspace is not zero and hence the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: How do you intuitively think of a projection? Like imagine? Can you also tell me that if "Pu" is the projection of a vector u from field F(nxn) and P is an kxl matrix, what all values k and l can take, and will the resultant have to lie in F(nxn) only.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you asked for a stable method for computing the inverse of an orthogonal projection matrix. Since projections are usually not invertible, as @Jim mentioned in his answer, you could use a Moore-Penrose Generalized Inverse (pseudoinverse) instead. It is described in depth on its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse).

It may additionally be helpful to note the following property:

> If $M$ is an orthogonal projection operator, then $M^{+} = M$.

$M^{+}$, of course, denoting the pseudoinverse.